# Why cant I access my vue app via ip adress?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I cant access my app using the ipv4 address, it works only from localhost.
I used vue cli to generate the template. heres the code :

I've tried to google it, but i found no answer that actually helps

package.json:

```
 {
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config 
     build/webpack.dev.conf.js --allowed-hosts 192.168.42.126",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  }
}
```

webpack.dev.conf.js:

```
devServer: {
clientLogLevel: 'warning',
host: '0.0.0.0',
historyApiFallback: {
  rewrites: [{
    from: /.*/,
    to: path.posix.join(config.dev.assetsPublicPath, 'index.html')
  }, ],
},
hot: true,
contentBase: false, // since we use CopyWebpackPlugin.
compress: true,
//host: HOST || config.dev.host,
port: PORT || config.dev.port,
open: config.dev.autoOpenBrowser,
overlay: config.dev.errorOverlay ?
  {
    warnings: false,
    errors: true
  } :
  false,
publicPath: config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
proxy: config.dev.proxyTable,
quiet: true, // necessary for FriendlyErrorsPlugin
watchOptions: {
  poll: config.dev.poll,
}
```

},

Comment: try to add `disableHostCheck: true` to dev server config.

Comment: Wow! thank you very much , it works! @MaxSinev